# SwaggerContextService class not found in swagger-jersey2-jaxrs maven artifect

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0, swagger-2.0

I have multiple Resource class and i don't know if i can use `@SwaggerDefinition` in all of them so i am trying to write a custom bootstrap servlet

I am fallowing the example in the fallowing link 
[Bootstrap for swagger-jersery2](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/blob/master/java/java-jersey2/src/main/java/io/swagger/sample/Bootstrap.java)

and i am not able to find `SwaggerContextService` class in any package .

So i tried

```
BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
beanConfig.configure(swagger);
```

even that is not working

My maven dependency looks like this

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
     <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

can some one help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a much older version of swagger. `SwaggerContextService` was added in 1.5.7 and the latest stable version is 1.5.13.